# jQuery: issues with mouseover event if the element has children

Tags: jquery

I have the following element:

```
<div id="#block-block-1">
    <p>KAREN LANCEL:<br>
lancel(at)xs4all.nl<br>
phone 0031 (0)624873424</p>
<p>HERMEN MAAT:<br>
maat(at)xs4all.nl<br>
phone 0031 (0)628536885</p>
</div>
```

which is supposed to disappear when the mouse is moved out of it (I will ignore now to talk about the fading in event).

This is the code to make it fading out:

```
$('#block-block-1').mouseout(function() {
        $(this).css("display","none");
    });
```

The issue here is that the 'mouseout' event is triggered when the mouse is over the children

elements inside my div. And the parent  disappears even if the mouse is still inside it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Mouseleave](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/) will do the trick for you.

PPK has some [excellent documentation](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_mouse.html) on what is actually happening and why mouseout isn't doing what you think it should at that point: technically, you are mousing out of the layer when you mouseover its children, which is a little odd conceptually.